# Why my HTACCESS is not working?

Tags: .htaccess

Here's my htaccess code. What's wrong? The 404 error is not working, but the code at the bottom (remove www and change index.html for root) works fine. I tried changing the 404 error URL for Google.com for example, and it was not working either.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404.html

Redirect 301 /location_entrepots.html http://example.com/index.html
Redirect 301 /mini_entrepots_residentiel.html http://example.com/nos-entrepots.html
Redirect 301 /mini_entrepots_commercial.html http://example.com/nos-entrepots.html
Redirect 301 /bureaux_a_louer.html http://example.com/bureaux-a-louer.html
Redirect 301 /visitevirtuelle.html http://example.com/medias.html
Redirect 301 /video.html http://example.com/medias.html
Redirect 301 /location_entrepots_dimensions.html http://example.com/nos-entrepots.html
Redirect 301 /location_camions.html http://example.com/location-de-camions.html
Redirect 301 /information_location_entrepots.html http://example.com/contact.html
Redirect 301 /contactez_nous.html http://example.com/contact.html
Redirect 301 /promotions.html http://example.com/index.html

Redirect 301 /storage_units_welcome.html http://example.com/en/home.html
Redirect 301 /residential_storage_units.html http://example.com/en/storage-units.html
Redirect 301 /commercial_storage_units.html http://example.com/en/storage-units.html
Redirect 301 /office_rental.html http://example.com/en/office-rental.html
Redirect 301 /virtualvisit.html http://example.com/en/medias.html
Redirect 301 /video_en.html http://example.com/en/medias.html
Redirect 301 /storage_rental_units_dimensions.html http://example.com/en/storage-units.html
Redirect 301 /truck_rental.html http://example.com/en/truck-rental.html
Redirect 301 /storage_rental_units_informations.html http://example.com/en/contact.html
Redirect 301 /contact_us.html http://example.com/en/contact.html
Redirect 301 /promotions_en.html http://example.com/en/home.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No, that's the only htaccess on the server, and I've pasted all the content of it. Any idea?

Comment: I just tried and it's not working :( Any other ideas? Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the full link, just the directory, for example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
```

or in your case (if your 404 page is on your root):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the reason why it's not working. I know "I don't have to", but it should work either way, right?

Comment: You would think, but I had a similar problem on my own 404 a while back and it seemed to work after the change, might be worth a test all the same. I also had to clear cache.

Comment: I just tried and it's not working. All my redirects gives me a default browser 404 error without even loading anything. Thanks though!

Comment: Really strange... and when you commented out everything else, it still did not display the correct 404 page?

Comment: Extactly. I know, really strange! Can it be a server issue?

Comment: It really depends, some hosts do not support custom 404 pages (although most do). Who're you hosted with? Does it specify if they support it or not? It might be a good idea to set up a local server to test it, or speak to your host to see if it is their end causing the problem, because your ErrorDocument is correct as far as I can tell from the above.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried on my local machine (using Mamp), and it's not working either. I checked, and my file is correctly named ".htaccess"...and the "remove www" function works, so it's not about the name of the file. I don't get it

Comment: Try renaming your 404 page to something else, like 'notfound' as a test, then reset your cache again. I don't see why this would affect anything, but looking at what you've got, there is no reason why this should not work :/.. Have you tested the 404 from other IPs / PCs? It could just be happening to you. What is your web address?

Comment: I'll try that. But I tested the same Htaccess on my website server (not my clients server), and it's working. So that probably means there's something going on with his server.

Comment: Yeh sounds like it will be their server. Sorry we couldn't find an easier solution.

Comment: No problem! Thanks a lot for trying. Any idea what can cause that issue on a server?